# Access database using AJAX in a Code Igniter project

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I asked this question 2 days ago, got 1 answer, but I didn't understand it. So, I am asking you if you guys have a better/easy option.

Look at this code snippet:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
       {
?>
           <div>
               <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" onkeypress="showUser()"/>
               <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $value['comment'];?>"/>
               <div id="comment"></div>
           </div>
<?php
       }
?>
```

Here, there are some `<div>` items, each having their own "textfield"s. What I want, my users will give their comments in that "textfield", and I'll get the corresponding comment-id from that `hidden` field. And when a user inputs a comment, this comment will be stored in the database and shown to the user(in the "comment" `<div>`), using that "id". I thought to use a normal `<form>` and let the user "submit" (a `submit` button) the comment. But that is time consuming, the whole page will be reloaded. So, I think AJAX is better for this thing. Its like "commenting" part of "Facebook".

This is my AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser()
    {
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which && e.which==13)
              {
                  $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>help/ajax_work_comment",
                  {
                      comment:this.value,
                      id:$(this).next('#id').attr('value');
                  })
              }
            else
              {}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Remember, this is a `Code Igniter` project, so "help" is a `Controller` and `ajax_work_comment` is a function in that `Controller`. Here is `ajax_work_comment()` function:

```
public function ajax_work_comment()
{
    $comment=$_POST["comment"];
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $this->load->model('help/model');

    $this->model->ajax_work_comment($comment,$id);
    echo $comment;
}
```

I know its very complex. Actually, I am a new web developer, that's why it became that complex and disgusting. Please help me.

Comment: What's the question here?  Does this work?  Not work?  What are you asking us?

Comment: +1 to the above. What's the issue? If you're storing the AJAX in a separate directory you will need to modify your .htaccess so it doesn't redirect to the index.php of CodeIgniter by default.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this code is not working, I can't storing users' comments in the database by this code. I think the problem is in the AJAX code.

Comment: @monkeymatrix I am not doing this, the .htaccess is alright and this AJAX code snippet is in a "view" file.

Comment: @user2387319 please paste the error here and if no error is occuring still comments are not storing then please paste your model code here

Answer (score 1):

check for javascript errors.

probably your js code has to be in the document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
};
```

also have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST["whatever"];` will probably fail.

Use `$this->input->post('comment');` and `$this->input->post('id');` instead.

And please provide more info next time.

Comment: Ok, I am gonna try this. Can you tell me what else do you need to see ? @Ahmed D. Sherif

Comment: can u download firebug "on firefox" and send me the post data "from network tab" and the received data and add print_r($this->input->post()) at the start of the function ajax_work_comment and get me the data again